# Force facebook connection to login popup

Tags: oauth, facebook-c#-sdk

How can I invoke the facebook connection without user click in facebook-button?

I have facebook login button in my Login.aspx, and other button in my Main.aspx who just redirect to Login.aspx. If user clicks on button of Main.aspx I want invoke facebook login button (open the litle popup bla bla bla.). If I don't do this, the user has to click 2 times to open the facebook dialog popup.

Any idea?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/ or https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/client-side/#no-jssdk

Comment: @CBroe it doesn't help.. what I want to do is call the function of facebook button without click in the button!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JavaScript... you need to call [FB.login](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/), that will open the login dialog.

Hope that helps.